# "Salade à la caesar et aux fines herbes" or "Salade à caesar et aux fines herbes"?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions, locutions, alimentation

Which sentence is the right one? Or are they both right?

> Salade à la caesar et aux fines herbes

or

> Salade à caesar et aux fines herbes

If only one sentence is the correct one, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 8):

> Salade César aux fines herbes.

*César* indique une recette de salade (comme l'on dit une *Pêche Melba*) , et non un constituant de cette dernière : donc pas de *à la* (que l'on peut comprendre comme ***à la*** façon de), César n'étant pas cuisinier.

*Aux fines herbes* donne la spécificité de la recette, l’accommodement choisi par le cuisinier et donc un ajout par rapport à la recette originale : comme il s'agit d'un complément, le *et* est inutile, sinon il y a deux plats : la salade *et* les fines herbes.

Développé, le nom du plat pourrait être :

> Salade faite selon la recette de César à laquelle on a ajouté des fines herbes.

Comment: On peut préciser qu'ici "César" est une recette (plutôt que "type" :) à l'appellation connue et qu'il faut que cette salade soit effectivement fidèle à la recette pour être nommée ainsi.
C'est la même chose entre "pissaladière" et "tarte à l'oignon", la deuxième n'a pas d'anchois ! :)

Comment: Thank you for answer, I understand french, though it is easier for me to explain in english. Sorry.

What if "Cesar" is not the type but a flavor? Example: "Biscotte à la cesar et aux fines herbes" is correct? This means that the product is flavored with fine herbs and cesar flavor.

Comment: If Caesar was a flavor, that would be "Biscotte au césar" but Caesar was a cook, not a taste. You might then say "Biscotte façon César aux fines herbes"..

Answer (score -2):

Ce n'est ni l'un ni l'autre, c'est tout simplement: ''Salade  caesar et aux fines herbes ''

Comment: Il manque la partie "can someone explain why?" de la réponse... :)

Comment: Le "et" me semble de trop ici. J'aurais plutôt dis "Salade caesar aux fines herbes".

Comment: De plus en français on écrit normalement avec l'accent et sans le _a_ :  _César_.